# Angular 6 font awesome icons shown as random characters

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, font-awesome

I have initiated a new project using the angular cli and installed font-awesome 4.7.0

then I add it as a dependncy in my angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

but when I build the application the fonts looks like:
[spinning cog, spin works icon not so much...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8EX.png)
and when I check the developer tool [the icon looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dww.png)
I tried to include the font awesome scss in my styles scss
Like other answers I've seen but to no avail
can anyone help in this issue?

Comment: Do bootstrap and primeng's css work though?

Comment: You need to reference the actual fonts in the `webfonts` folder as well as the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of say fa-circle pass fa fa-circle in the class. It stopped working for me when I upgraded to angular 6 from 4. But adding fa did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add the reference to the font.
For example, in my project I used fontawesome-free-webfonts and then I added, in the styles.css this variable that points to the folder (the path is refered to fontawesome v.5):

```
$fa-font-path: '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/webfonts';
```

If it works, you can also move all the other references for the css files to styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome has an official Angular component that’s available for all who want to use their icons in projects.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular